# How to fix content that is wider then screen on mobile

Tags: html, css

I've got a login form that is attached with a CSS file, it displays fine on desktop but on mobile the form displays really small and you have to zoom in with fingers to type on it.

I want the form to automatically be in the same size of the clients screen (on mobile).

Who can help on that?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
html,
body {
  background: #6665ee;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

::selection {
  color: #3d3d3d;
  background: #3d3d3d;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 440px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container .form {
  max-width: 440px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.container .form form .form-control {
  height: auto;
  font-size: auto;
}

.container .form form .forget-pass {
  margin: -15px 0 15px 0;
}

.container .form form .forget-pass a {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container .form form .button {
  background: #6665ee;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.container .form form .button:hover {
  background: #5757d1;
}

.container .form form .link {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.container .form form .link a {
  color: #6665ee;
}

.container .login-form form p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container .row .alert {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <p>Paragraph.</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and post some HTML as well. It's hard to help with just CSS.

Comment: to broad for SO. `Responsive Web Design` is a whole concept that is way out of scope for SO. I recommend you to read up on using `media queries` first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is to broad and conceptional. It is either missing focus to be specific enough for SO and/or is opinion-based as it is conceptional.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is your viewport and not your CSS. Try adding this line into your `<head>` element:

```
<!-- Disables Scaling on multi-touch interfaces -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

This basically tells the browser to adjust to mobile devices.

Comment: no this does not tell a browser toa djust to mobile devices. it oevrrules the difference between hardware and software pixels on high density mobile devices. which making the website even smaller and less readable by default.

Comment: You might be right, but please don't guess at poor questions.

Comment: Lol, who hurt yall? Just trying to help!